# how to add hyperlink in datarow dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I am developing an attendance application using asp.net. I am showing the record of the person according to their **ID** from day 1 to last day of the month and I also want to display their all details when I click on particular date.

I am using **DataRow** and create dynamic row of the month according to the day(s) of the month and displaying their data (Present or Absent).

I am not Understanding how can I convert (present or absent) as a link in gridview so that I can fetch all the details by click them.

Here is the code :

```
private void BindData()

{
    string queryText = "";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Columns.Add("UserID");
    table.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Location");
    //table.Columns.Add("Days");
    row[0] = Convert.ToString("");
    row[1] = Convert.ToString("");
    row[2] = Convert.ToString("");

    num = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, Convert.ToInt32(this.drpmonth.SelectedValue));

    string str2 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(string.Concat(new object[] { "01/", this.drpmonth.SelectedValue, "/", DateTime.Now.Year })).ToString("d"));

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        row[i + 2] = this.GetAbbriviateDay(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(string.Concat(new object[] { i, "/", this.drpmonth.SelectedValue, "/", DateTime.Now.Year })).DayOfWeek));
    }

    table.Rows.Add(row);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtemplID.Text) && (this.txtemplID.Text.Trim() != ""))
    {
        queryText = "SELECT  EmpID, CONCAT(Fname, ' ', Lname) AS EmployeeName FROM  **[table_name]** where `EmpID`='" + this.txtemplID.Text.Trim() + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        queryText = "SELECT  EmpID, CONCAT(Fname, ' ', Lname) AS EmployeeName FROM  **[table_name]** order by EmpID desc";
    }
    DataTable table2 = AssetDatabaseConnection.ExecuteQuery(queryText);

    DataTable table3 = AssetDatabaseConnection.ExecuteQuery("Select a.EmpID,b.location_name as Location, b.Currentt_Date,case When  sum(timestampdiff(HOUR,b.In_Entry,b.Out_Entry)) is null  Then '0.00'   ELSE cast(sum(timestampdiff(Minute,b.In_Entry,b.Out_Entry))/60 as char)  End as TotalHors from GPS_Login a left join **[table_name]** as b on a.EmpID=b.User_ID   where month(b.Currentt_Date)='" + this.drpmonth.SelectedValue + "'  and   year(b.Currentt_Date)=YEAR(NOW())   group by b.Currentt_Date,a.EmpID order by  b.Currentt_Date asc");

    if (table2.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < table2.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            int num4 = 0;
            row = table.NewRow();
            ViewState["EmpID"] = Convert.ToString(table2.Rows[j]["EmpID"]);
            row[0] = Convert.ToString(table2.Rows[j]["EmpID"]);
            row[1] = Convert.ToString(table2.Rows[j]["EmployeeName"]);
            ViewState["EmpName"] = Convert.ToString(table2.Rows[j]["EmployeeName"]);
            //row[2] = Convert.ToString(table2.Rows[j]["Location"]);
            for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
            {
                num4 = 0;
                if (table3.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row2 in table3.Rows)
                    {
                        string str3 = Convert.ToDateTime(row2["Currentt_Date"]).ToString("d");
                        ViewState["Curr_Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row2["Currentt_Date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        string str4 = Convert.ToDateTime(str2).AddDays((double)k).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        string str5 = Convert.ToString(table2.Rows[j]["EmpID"]);
                        string str6 = Convert.ToString(row2["EmpID"]);
                        string Loc = Convert.ToString(row2["Location"]);
                        if ((str3 == str4) && (str5 == str6))
                        {
                            num4 = 1;
                            if (Convert.ToDouble(row2["TotalHors"]) >= 9.0)
                            {
                                row[k + 3] = "P"; 
                                row[2] = Loc;
                            }
                            else if (Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(row2["TotalHors"]), 2) == 0.0)
                            {
                                row[k + 3] = "A";
                                row[2] = Loc;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row[k + 3] = "S";
                                //row[k + 3] = "S(" + Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row2["TotalHors"]), 2) + ")";
                                //ViewState["ShortLeave"] = "S(" + Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row2["TotalHors"]), 2) + ")";
                                row[2] = Loc;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (num4 == 0)
                    {
                        row[k + 3] = "A";
                    }
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    this.grdattendanceDetail.DataSource = table;
    this.grdattendanceDetail.DataBind();
}
```

and after that I am creating dynamic link button inside gridview using Rowdatabound but after click on link it conver as a text here is the code of rowdatabound :

protected void grdattendanceDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

```
 {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, int.Parse(Session["SelectedMonth"].ToString()));
                days += 3;
                for (int i = 3; i <= days; i++)
                {
                    if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "A")
                    {
                        LinkButton lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn.ID = "AttendanceID";
                        lnkbtn.Text = "A";
                        lnkbtn.ToolTip = "Absent";
                        //lnkbtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        //lnkbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        lnkbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#8C4510");
                        //lnkbtn.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtn_Click);
                        lnkbtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(AttendanceID_Click);
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(lnkbtn);
                    }
                    else if(e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "P")
                    {
                        LinkButton lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn.ID = "AttendanceID";
                        lnkbtn.Text = "P";
                        lnkbtn.ToolTip = "Present";
                        lnkbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#8C4510");
                        //lnkbtn.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtn_Click);
                        lnkbtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(AttendanceID_Click);
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(lnkbtn);
                    }
                    else if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "S")
                    {
                        LinkButton lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn.ID = "AttendanceID";
                        lnkbtn.Text = "S";
                        lnkbtn.ToolTip = "Short Leave";
                        lnkbtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#8C4510");
                        //lnkbtn.Click += new EventHandler(AttendanceID_Click);
                        lnkbtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(AttendanceID_Click);
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(lnkbtn);
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
        }
    }
```

screenshot of the output :

[A , S , P are links so that I can show one day details of the candidate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CybK4.png)

Comment: give examples of what you have, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        table.Columns.Add("UserID");
        table.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Location");
        row[0] = Convert.ToString("");
        row[1] = Convert.ToString("");
        row[2] = Convert.ToString("");

if (Convert.ToDouble(row2["TotalHors"]) >= 9.0)
                                {
                                    row[k + 3]  = "P"; //I want to convert this as a hyperlink
                                    row[2] = Loc;
                                }

Comment: add this detail to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: how you are rendering data, using gridview? give code

Comment: I added my code with screenshot. Please help.